# Java: Converting String to Date

Tags: java, string, date, parsing, simpledateformat

I am trying to get the current date in a Talend job and I am using this as my context variable:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = new Date();
context.dateout = dateFormat.format(date);

System.out.println(context.dateout);
```

However, the type of the result is a String and not a Date.
How should I correct it?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: What is "the result"? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the desired behavior.

Comment: `format` is the operation to turn a `Date` into a `String`. The inverse is named `parse`.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a `Date` to the same `Date` ? Why not just `context.dateout=date;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do that according the following code:

```
String string = "2016-03-15";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
try {
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(string);
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

I don't know what your `context.dateout` means.

Answer (score 2):

Note the difference between parse and format.

This is to create a string from a date:

```
dateFormat.format(date);
```

This is to create a date from a string:

```
dateFormat.parse(dateString);
```